# getting uiswitch value in cell from UIViewController class

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have a view controller with a UITableView. The Table View has 2 cells. One of the cells has a UISwitch.

Within the cell class I declare the UISwitch

```
    cellSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

and a function

```
func switchChanged(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    let value = mySwitch.isOn
    // Do something
    print("mySwitch.isOn: \(value)")

}
```

How do i know which instance of the UISwitch I changed.I have several forming at runtime

Comment: You mean with in single cell you are having multiple UISwitch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating a cell, add the datasource index as `UISwitch` tag.

At the time of `UISwitch` value change, get the tag value of the control. And get the data from datasource array by using the index value which you get it via control tag.

**You should implement UISwitch value change method in the UIViewController. Otherwise you have to pass the datasource array to every cell, which is not good.**

**Cell Creation**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = // Your code here ....

        // Implement UISwitch action method in the UIViewController only.
        cell.cellSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

        cell.cellSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
}
```

**Switch Value Changed:**

```
func switchChanged(mySwitch: UISwitch) {

    let value = mySwitch.isOn
    // Do something
    print("mySwitch.isOn: \(value)")

    // tag will give you the index of the data model.
    let index = mySwitch.tag

    //dataSourceArray is your tableview data source array. You can't get this array from cell. so better you should implement UISwitch value change method in the UIViewController. 
    let model = dataSourceArray[index];

    // Now you got the model to update based on switch value change.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In your custom cell class , Just create outlet and action  of UISwitch button from storyBoard as below**

```
import UIKit
protocol CellDelegate: class {
    func didTapCell(index: IndexPath)
}
class CustomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
 @IBOutlet weak var switchButton: UIButton!
 var delegateCell:CellDelegate?
 var indexPath:IndexPath?

 @IBAction func yourSwitchButton(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
        delegateCell?.didTapCell(index: indexPath!)
    }
}
```

**In your ViewController Class**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,CellDelegate {
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: 
     indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.delegateCell = self
    cell.indexPath = indexPath
 }
 func didTapCell(index: IndexPath){
    print("YOU SELECTED SWITCH   \(index.row)")
  }
}
```